# Problem with: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I was goin through some tutorial, and i got into an issue with The error 'cannot read property 'map' of undefined'.Please help me with the following code.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
TodoItems.render
C:/Users/hp/Desktop/todo_list/src/TodoItems.js:10

```
 7 | 
   8 |    render(){
   9 |        var todoEntries = this.props.entries;
> 10 |        var listItems = todoEntries.map(this.createTasks);
     | ^  11 | 
  12 |        return (
  13 |            <ul className="theList">
View compiled
▶ 23 stack frames were collapsed.

import React, { Component } from "react";

class TodoItems extends Component{
    createTasks(item) {
        return <li key={item.key}>{item.text}</li>
    }

    render(){
        var todoEntries = this.props.entries;
        var listItems = todoEntries.map(this.createTasks);

        return (
            <ul className="theList">
                {listItems}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default TodoItems;


and the TodoList file code is:
render() {
        return (
            <div className="todoListMain">
            <div className="header">
                <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
                    <input ref={(a) => this._inputElement = a}
                         placeholder="enter task">
                    </input>
                    <button type="submit">add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <TodoItems entries={this.state.items}/>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: do `var todoEntries = this.props.entries || [];` you don't have items in state in your `TodoList` component.

Comment: the problem is solved but it is not taking the entries and displaying them.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass `this.state.items` as `entries`, but it seems that it's not an array but `undefined`.

You could just make it an array by default by doing something like the following -

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    items: []
  }
}
```

Comment: class TodoList extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        item: []
    };
    
    this.additem = this.additem.bind(this);
}
this is my code and yes i made sure it is an array

Comment: @Aishwarya `item` is not `items`

Comment: @Aishwarya you wrote `item` while the correct word according to your code is `items`. Try fixing that